# Xcode archives have duplicate embedded frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

When archiving my application target in Xcode, I am seeing nested framework bundles in the archive. In my project, I have a framework called `SpinlisterUIKit`, which links to 3rd party frameworks (I am using Carthage). I have the 3rd party frameworks embedded in the parent project.

[image: Here is a screen shot of the archive's contents for more context]
You can see MMNumberKeyboard is both in the `Frameworks` directory of the application, and the `Frameworks` directory of `SpinlisterUIKit`. I'm not sure why frameworks are being embedded in the `SpinlisterUIKit` framework. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. Inside of my `SpinlisterUIKit` framework, I had a `Copy Frameworks` phase that copied the 3rd party framework into `SpinlisterUIKit`.

[image]